# How to fix 'User login. Teams is disabled for your tenant.' error in graph api call

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I want to use Teams graph api to retrieve all channels of a team (group).

I use a 'Get' request on 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/{GroupId}/channels'

The response is 'Access Denied', 'User login. Teams is disabled for your tenant.'

Other informations:

- I don't have any issue when I use Teams app (web or desktop), the user is the owner of the team (group).
- The user is under Office 365 F1 license with teams activated.
- He possess the 'security administrator' role.
- I retrieve the teams by the get request : 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/memberOf', that work fine.
- I got the same error with : 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/joinedTeams'
- I use an application with "group.ReadWrite.all" and "user.Read.all" rights and the connexion uses a bearer token.
- It's not my environment so I can't give the permissions for graph Api Explorer, I m not admin. So with the graph Api Explorer i get a 403, forbidden request.

If anyone can help.
Thanks

ANSWER : The problem is the F1 license that work with Graph API but with some restrictions. You should use E3 to E5 license, there give full right on Graph API.

Comment: Could you please check if your token has required permission using https://jwt.io/#debugger-io?

Comment: Group.ReadWrite.All requires tenant administrator permissions. Security administrator permissions are not sufficient. @Wajeed-MSFT's suggestion is a good one - verify that the token actually has Group.ReadWrite.All and User.Read.All permissions.

Comment: @Wajeed Group.ReadWrite.All is in the token, you can see it below : 
"scp": "Directory.AccessAsUser.All Directory.ReadWrite.All Group.ReadWrite.All Member.Read.Hidden User.Read.All User.ReadBasic.All",
  "sub": "VCBCT_Lht8I5eXB5tFCZ5hFmNQuRxNhAZLnbp_KnMk8",
  "tid": "47abbbbc-b105-437d-9a5f-1d3953dc944f", …

Comment: @BillBliss-MSFT, I understand what you are saying but on a Microsoft demo tenant i can use my code without problem using an user with just security administrator permission… I don't think the problem is in my code or the user configuration (except maybe the F1 license, but SunnySun said it wasn't the problem) I m pretty sure it s a tenant configuration but i don't know how to activate teams on the tenant, I read it wa not necessary anymore...

Comment: Could you please provide [User License details](https://graph.microsoft/v1.0/users/{user-id}/licenseDetails) to [Microsoft Teams developer support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/feedback) email alias?

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT, I did a microsoft ticket and I got my answer.

The F1 License agree to use the graph API but with some restrictions.
And E3, E4, E5 license give full right on graph API.

Tankh you.

Answer (score 0):

On my side, both of them work well with the O365 user license.

```
GET 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/{teamId}/channels
```

[image]

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/joinedTeams
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, when I use my tenant (Microsoft demo tenant) with an similar user except the license office 365 E3 that works fine.

But my problems occurs on a tenant I m not administrator (client) so I can't give the permission for the graph api explorer…

I use an application with some rights: Group.ReadWrite.All (for our case) and a connexion by bearer token

Comment: Microsoft Teams is available in Office 365 Business Essentials, Office 365 Business Premium, Office 365 Enterprise (E1, E3, E5, F1), and the Office 365 Education plans. For the details, you could read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/servicedescriptions/office-365-platform-service-description/office-365-platform-service-description).

Comment: What flow you used to get the bearer token?

Comment: I use this: https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TenantId}/oauth2/token with arguments: client id (the app id), client secret (the app secret), grantype : password, user login and user password

Answer (score 0):

WARNING !
When you use graph API (Teams particulary) the user should have E3 to E5 license.
The F1 license work too but with some restrictions.
I will add the restrictions later in my post.

Thanks for everyone help.